# Prevent a certain command

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to prevent a certain command in a folder or globally? I just need to prevent

```
git merge staging
```

I've tried with git hooks but with no success.

Comment: It's not possible to prevent someone performing that operation because there are far too many work arounds in git which would produce exactly the same result.  Blocking the command to prevent accidental usage might be difficult, although you could replace `git` with an alias that checks the arguments first.

Comment: Would you need to prevent merging that branch on a particular machine, or anywhere where someone has cloned the repository? Or would it be enough to prevent other people from pushing to some central repository (since any aspect of a local git repository can be changed locally)?

Comment: @Kusalananda the command doesn't change `staging`, it uses `staging` by merging it into other code.  No matter what the OP is after, its not possible because you can merge by commit number and therefore find the commit number for `staging` and merge that into the current branch with the same effect.

Comment: I need to prevent merging that branch on feature branches. I have a feature branch on my local machine and the staging branch on a remote machine where things are tested with non-released stuff. Merging staging on my feature branch means trouble.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I know.

Comment: @MihaiM This sounds like one of those "how can I prevent `rm -rf /`?" questions. The answer is "don't do that then".

Comment: @Kusalananda you are right. I just wanted a safety net.

Comment: Here a safety net might be to undo it if you do it by mistake.  Eg:  [`git reset HEAD^`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556501/git-how-to-reset-after-merging)

Answer (score 0):

I used the prepare-commit-msg hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Prevent merging staging branch in feature branch

if cat "$1" | grep "staging"; then
  echo "\033[31m DO NOT MERGE staging BRANCH!"
  exit 1
fi
```